# map sql column to date based on an end date

Tags: mysql, sql, sybase

I have a pay period sybase table containing column names day01 - day14. I also have a column containing the pay period end date. Management is requesting the hours used for all the Mondays in the month of July.

How can I walk the column names mapping them to dates so I can get all Mondays in the month of July using sybase?

data example

```
Time_Sheet_Hours

day01 | day02 | day03 ... day14 | end_date
7.5   | 7.5   | 0 ...           | 2017-07-05

day01 | day02 | day03 ... day14 | end_date
7.5   | 7.5   | 7.5 ...         | 2017-07-19

day01 | day02 | day03 ... day14 | end_date
7.5   | 7.5   | 7.5 ...         | 2017-08-02
```

Can you somehow do a nested query where the from could be dynamic based on the column sequence and mapped to a date based on the end_date?

Comment: Sybase or MySQL? Or is this question related to both?

Comment: What a strange way to store data.  However, since 14 days is two weeks, you must know which of the columns are always Monday.  If your weeks starts on a Sunday, then all column day02 and day09 are Mondays.  You might start by creating a temporary table that assigns a date to each day02/end_date combination and each day09/end_date combination.

Comment: Sybase is the main database, but we have test database is in mysql. Yes it's a very strange way to store the data. If there is an expert in either of the two databases that could help put us on the correct path, we could figure out the other database. We just know sybase support is pretty weak.

Comment: @Degan, is there a dynamic way to normalize this data without using a temp table?

Comment: Fix your broken design

Comment: @Strawberry I didn't build or design the data model, nor is it my job to redesign  the data model, I've only been tasked with trying to help build a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`datepart`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1570/html/blocks/X71771.htm) in Sybase, or [`dayofweek`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) in mysql, to determine the numeric day of the week (Sunday is 1) that end_date falls on. Then you can determine how many more days until "day 2" (Monday - not your "day02" column). Then either use a case statement, or execute a dynamic query, in order to sum up the correct day.

Here is an example in Sybase. It assumes that day14 is also the end_date.
Therefore, if end_date is a Sunday, then that means day14 was also a Sunday, and day01 and day08 represent Mondays.

```
select 
sum
(
    case 
        when (datepart(dw, end_date) = 1) then day01 + day08 -- Ends on Sun
        when (datepart(dw, end_date) = 7) then day02 + day09 -- Ends on Sat
        when (datepart(dw, end_date) = 6) then day03 + day10 -- Ends on Fri
        when (datepart(dw, end_date) = 5) then day04 + day11 -- Ends on Thu
        when (datepart(dw, end_date) = 4) then day05 + day12 -- Ends on Wed
        when (datepart(dw, end_date) = 3) then day06 + day13 -- Ends on Tue
        when (datepart(dw, end_date) = 2) then day07 + day14 -- Ends on Mon
        else 0
    end
)
from my_table
```

Comment: That's a good point about not needing to do 2 weeks worth of day calcs..

Comment: @Robbie Toyota would this query have the capability to stay within the month. Example if the pay period ends on the 3rd and we need to get all the hours worked on a wednesday, would it be capable of not extracting dates prior to the 1st?

Comment: @CodeJunkie This specific query would not be able to do that, but it can be modified to. You can use `datepart(dd, end_date)` to find the day of the month that day14 falls on (assuming it's the same as end_date). Then include a check of the day in the case statement. You'll also need to break the things like `day01 + day08` into separate `when` statements. For example: `when (datepart(dw, end_date) = 1 and datepart(dd, end_date) >= 14) then day01` and repeat for day08: `when (datepart(dw, end_date) = 1 and datepart(dd, end_date) >= 7) then day08`.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of brute case when should do it:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN dayofweek(end_date - INTERVAL 13 day) = 2 THEN day01 END +
  CASE WHEN dayofweek(end_date - INTERVAL 12 day) = 2 THEN day02 END +
  ... -- and so on. Writing this out on an iPad is a pain
  CASE WHEN dayofweek(end_date - INTERVAL 1 day) = 2 THEN day13 END +
  CASE WHEN dayofweek(end_date - INTERVAL 0 day) = 2 THEN day14 END
  as sum_of_mondays
FROM time sheet
WHERE end_date BETWEEN x AND y
```

Do please examine this for real with your data; check that the dayofweek() calc on the adjusted date really does correctly identify the Mondays- I've no MySQL instance to try this on but the docs say that dayofweek returns 2 for a Monday, and I've assumed that end_date and day14 are the same day hence subrptracting 0 days from it. If your end_date is midnight after the day upon which day14's hours are worked, then you'll need to adjust the subtracts by one (I.e. Subs should start by subtracting 14, and finish by subtracting 1)

Comment: As per Robbie toyotas solution, it's not actually necessary to list out the full 2 weeks like I did in my pattern; it can be simplified by doing 7 days worth of calcs and adding e.g. Day01 and Day07 after the THEN

Comment: I'll try your suggestion on Monday. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't specifically answer my original question, I'd like to share our end solution. The end solution was to just build a view to query against which contained normalized data.